# I keep getting Error Message 1064 when running create table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySQL and ran into a little trouble with a project I'm working on. I keep getting an error message #1064- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','

Table structure for table `ea_cellcarrier`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ea_cellcarrier(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  ',' PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ) ,
cellco VARCHAR( 30 )  ','cellurl VARCHAR( 30 )
)
```

Constraints for dumped tables

Constraints for table `ea_appointments`

```
ALTER TABLE  `ea_appointments` 
ADD CONSTRAINT  `ea_appointments_ibfk_2` 
                 FOREIGN KEY (  `id_users_customer` ) 
                 REFERENCES  `ea_users` (  `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
ADD CONSTRAINT  `ea_appointments_ibfk_3` 
                 FOREIGN KEY (  `id_services` ) 
                 REFERENCES  `ea_services` (  `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
ADD CONSTRAINT  `ea_appointments_ibfk_4` 
                 FOREIGN KEY (  `id_users_provider` ) 
                 REFERENCES  `ea_users` (  `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '','  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), cellco VARCHAR(30)','  cellurl
>   VARCHAR(30)) Co' at line 5

Comment: this is MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Why do you have single quotes around your commas ? *... ',' ...*??

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ea_cellcarrier
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  cellco  VARCHAR(30) ,
  cellurl VARCHAR(30) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
)
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question, one should also explain why and how the problem is solved